# .htaccesss: allow to load resource files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to do the following.

1. denied directly access to example.domain.com
2. allow access from to example.domain.com from another.domain.com
3. allow to load resource files (css, js) when the the user comes form another.domain.com to example.domain.com

Points 1 and 2 i solved like this:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?another\.domain\.com\/$ [NC] RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]`

But i can not to load resource files. I get the error message 403.
I tried with this code, but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.html|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^.*$ ^.*$ [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?another\.domain\.com\/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

I am a quite new with htaccess, can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following .htaccess rules file. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?another\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://example.domain.com/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?:index\.html|robots\.txt)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: thank you RavinderSingh13, it works fine! i found another solution, but i think your way is better

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.+(\.js|\.css|\.json|\.jpg|\.png|\.woff2|\.woff|\.ttf)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?another\.domain\.com\/$ [NC
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).